# `explode` delimiter not found behavior

Tags: php, split

I want `explode` to return an empty array if the delimiter is not found.

Currently, I do something like this to get the `explode` behavior I want:

```
            if (strpos($line, ' ') === false) {
                $entries = [];
            } else {
                $entries = explode(' ', $line);
            }
```

There must be a more concise way of getting this behavior without having to use `preg_split`. `preg_split` has its own behavior that is also undesirable, such as including the delimiter in the resultant array entries.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: is there a more concise way of getting the behavior i detailed in the question?

Comment: perhaps: `if ($entries[0]==$line){...`

Comment: better: `if (count($entries) === 1) $entries = [];`

Comment: How / where is the data generated? This sounds like something that should be handled where the data is validated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you have a string of *space delimited* data, e.g. `'foo bar'`? Your rule is if there's no delimiter, meaning if the string is either a single value (`'foo'`) or an empty string (`''`), then you want an empty array; otherwise you want the split delimited data?

```
$entries = explode(' ', $line);
if (count($entries) < 2) {
    $entries = [];
}
```

There isn't really a sane way to make this specific condition shorter, but this removes the redundant inspection of the string and clearly states what the code is trying to do.